# PayPal IPN Sandbox - Changing the Notification URL will not update

Tags: php, paypal

I had set a URL as my 'Notification URL' - https://example.com/ppl-name1.php - in my PayPal sandbox account.
It worked fine and testing went well.
I decided to rename my 'Notification URL' to https://example.com/ppl-name2.php.

I updated the detail with the new URL here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify

It accepted and saved the new URL.

But now paypal still sends the notifications to the old URL.
No matter how many times I try - even deleting the saved URL setting and turning off notifications and turning them back on.

It still will not send to the new URL.
Yet it clearly shows the new URL as the saved value.

I have verified the old URL is being called in the IPN History page.

Answer (score 0):

Check which information did you sent in your HTTP request to PayPal.

There is option "notify_url" where you instruct PayPal where to send IPN notification that should override your setting in PayPal panel.

Comment: Although this is true - papal offers an option to add a notify URL in the HTML button code - this does not answer my question as to why "updating the IPN Notify URL does not upstate on PayPal"